# git merge remote branches without having to create a local branch

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Title says it all.

So my company has these branches out on git hub:

```
origin/master ( use this for dev )
origin/QA
origin/staging
origin/live
```

locally I have

```
 master  ( a branch of origin/master ).
```

I would like to be able to move origin/QA to origin/staging.

The only option I can think would be to clone origin/staging to my local box, merge in origin/QA and then push my local staging branch up to origin/staging.

eg:

```
git checkout -b origin/staging
git merge origin/QA
git push;
```

I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do this as i'm having to create a random branch locally... Probably breaking some other good practices as well. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I would like to be able to move origin/QA to origin/staging"
If that quote is literally what you want to do then the following will accomplish it.  You just tell the remote to update it's reference "QA" to point to the SHA that "origin/staging" is sitting on.  If QA and Staging are diverged this might not be what you want to do.  Also if other people have local work sitting on QA you would be moving it out from under them and they would need to "recover from upstream rebase"

```
git push -f origin origin/staging:QA
```

If that isn't what you want to do then please update your question with more info.

Comment: So the above command will update update origin/staging's SHA to point to origin/QA's SHA? I believe that is what i'd like to but I don't want to Move QA out from under other developer as they may be working on QA.  Staging should only be updated from what's on QA so they shouldn't diverge.

Comment: No, it will move the QA reference on your remote to point to the same sha as staging.  If you want the reverse just reverse the references around the colon.  `git push sha_in_my_repo_to_use_as_the_update:reference_on_remote_to_update`

Comment: I would like to "move origin/QA to origin/staging"

Comment: Hi Ray - I promise I'm not trying to be intentionally daft here. 'origin/QA' is a ref in Git terminology (which means it is a file that points to a single SHA.  So one meaning of "move origin/QA" is "change the SHA that origin/QA points to".  This is how I interpreted your question.  It appears you are saying "I have a bunch of commits reachable only from the origin/QA reference, and I would like origin/staging to point to those same commits".  Which is the exact opposite.

Comment: ya sorry that can be pretty confusing.  That actually makes a lot more sense when thinking of it as pointers.  I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes.  thanks!